# Python Instagram Bot

Tags: python, automation, instagram

I have written an Instagram Liking bot with python. The Liking function is:

## Liking photos

```
    unique_photos = len(pic_hrefs)
    for pic_href in pic_hrefs:
        driver.get(pic_href)
        time.sleep(2)

        try:
          time.sleep(random.randint(4, 15))
          like_button = lambda: driver.find_element_by_class_name("_8-yf5 ").click()
          like_button().click()

          for second in reversed(range(0, random.randint(18, 28))):
             print_same_line("#" + hashtag + ': unique photos left: ' + str(unique_photos)
                            + " | Sleeping " + str(second))
             time.sleep(2) 
        except Exception as e:
          time.sleep(2)
        unique_photos -= 1
```

I want to add now a Likecount with alike limit. I also want  to check if I already liked a picture and skip that  one. How can I do that?

Comment: I'd imagine the class will change if the photo is already liked -- so you could check that

Comment: Also, you do know this exists right? https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot

Comment: The class does note change when the pciture is liked and yeah I know but I want to learn python and I thought this is a easy project to begin with...

Comment: Something in the html must change when it's liked/unliked -- debug using "inspect element" on chrome and you will see a change